# camel batch sql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, apache-camel

I'm trying to create a REST endpoint that reads data from a MySQL database given an array of unique ids using apache camel and returns it as a JSON object.

For a single ID it is as simple as making this query.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=#:id
```

I tried using

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN #:ids
```

but could not find a way to pass the array into the query.
Also, given that the arrays could be quite large I would prefer to use select batching. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Camel SQL component](https://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) your named parameter looks correct. All you have to do is set the value for `ids` as a header, see the [named parameter docs](https://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html#SQLComponent-Usingnamedparameters):

```
<from <!-- your endpoint --> />
  <setHeader header="ids">
    <constant>42</constant>
  </setHeader>
<to <!-- your sql component endpoint --> />
```